# Hough Line Transform in Python keeps throwing error

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

I'm trying to use opencv to do a simple Lane Keep Assist System but I'm getting this error from the Hough Transform function:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0)
> /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:155: error: (-215:Assertion
> failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function
> 'convertToShow'

This is the code I have:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def detect_line_segments(frame):
    # tuning min_threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap is a trial and error process by hand
    rho = 1  # distance precision in pixel, i.e. 1 pixel
    angle = np.pi / 180  # angular precision in radian, i.e. 1 degree
    min_threshold = 2  # minimal of votes
    # frame = frame.astype(np.uint8)
    line_segments = cv2.HoughLinesP(frame, rho, angle, min_threshold, minLineLength=8, maxLineGap=4)
    return line_segments

def detectEdges(frame):

    rho = 1
    angle = np.pi / 180
    min_threshold = 10
    
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_blue = np.array([60, 40, 40])
    upper_blue = np.array([150, 255, 255])
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (960, 540))

    # cv2.imshow('Test', mask)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)

    edges = cv2.Canny(mask, 200, 400)
    #edgesUpdt = np.array(edges, dtype=np.uint8)
    # cv2.imshow('Test', edgesUpdt)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    return edges

def region_of_interest(edges):
    print(edges)
    height, width = edges.shape
    mask = np.zeros_like(edges)

    # only focus bottom half of the screen
    polygon = np.array([[
        (0, height * 1 / 2),
        (width, height * 1 / 2),
        (width, height),
        (0, height),
    ]], np.int32)

    cv2.fillPoly(mask, polygon, 255)
    cropped_edges = cv2.bitwise_and(edges, mask)
    cv2.imshow('Test', cropped_edges)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return cropped_edges

def detect_line_segments(cropped_edges):
    # cropped_edges = cropped_edges.astype(np.float32)
    cv2.imshow('Test', cropped_edges)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # tuning min_threshold, minLineLength, maxLineGap is a trial and error process by hand
    rho = 2  # distance precision in pixel, i.e. 1 pixel
    angle = np.pi / 60  # angular precision in radian, i.e. 1 degree
    min_threshold = 50  # minimal of votes
    line_segments = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_edges, rho, angle, min_threshold, 
                                    np.array([], dtype=np.uint8), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=80)
    cv2.imshow('Test', line_segments)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return line_segments

def main():
    frame = cv2.imread(r'/home/a1ph4/Desktop/LKAS system/Media/image.jpg')
    edges = detectEdges(frame)
    # test1 = region_of_interest(edges)
    croppedEdges = detect_line_segments(edges)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the image I'm using
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVh3B.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: Comment this line: `edgesUpdt = np.array(edges, dtype=np.uint8)` and return `edges` instead. What happens?

Comment: I have done that. But the error persists.

Comment: What line is throwing the error? It seems you are passing an unsupported type to imshow.

Comment: Yes. The imshow line is the one that's throwing the error. But I have no idea on how to fix it. Most people are suggesting that the type be np.uint8 and it is already np.uint8. I have also tried to convert to type npfloat32 but it's not working.

Comment: We can't see this croppedEdges = detect_line_segments(edges)

Comment: There is nothing wrong. It worked for me.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Does it mark the edges of the road?

Comment: Yes. with all 2 pics, instead of 3 pics. It can detected blue.

Comment: Anyway to attach images to see your output?